# TListView change color from existing item android platform

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, tlistview, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I need some example how to change color text item for each row from my [list view](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListView.TListView) in FireMonkey.

I try something like this but unsuccessfully.

```
 for i := 0 to lvArtikli.ItemCount-1 do
        begin

          AItem := lvArtikli.Items.AppearanceItem[i];

          pk := AItem.Data['txtPK'].AsString;

          if pk = '' then
          begin
             //change color
            TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('txtPK')).TextColor := TAlphaColorRec.Red;

          end;

  end;
```

Comment: @RBA This is for android and i do not think the above (link) example includes the same platform.

Comment: @RBA I did.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to color a certain column, and for each row it is necessary to put the following code on event onUpdateObjects.

```
procedure TfrmMeni.lvKorektivnoUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin

TListItemText(AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('txtPK') as TListItemText).TextColor:= TAlphaColorRec.Gold;

end;
```